# Recommended approach to deploy VMware PowerCLI command line console application

Tags: deployment, command-line, console, vmware, powercli

PowerCLI with .NET has some dependencies on dll's that you get only when you install PowerCLI on each machine you want to run.
I have a console app with command line arguments, which when deployed using the usual method doesn't work because of the unmet dependencies...these assemblies are part of the GAC.

Clickonce deployment proved to be useless..it didnt recognize my arguments although I passed them as query params.

Finally, I installed VMware PowerCLI on this remote machine. Then ran the .exe and it worked. Is there a way to avoid installing PowerCLI and be able to include all the dependencies with my exe during deployment?

Comment: You can use the install wrapper that I wrote to deploy PowerCLI silently with out having to reboot the machine also. The script takes the Install parameter and Uninstall. Here's the link:
[SCCM PowerCLI Silent deployment script](http://www.sccmog.com/sccm-powercli-silent-deployment-script/) Hope that helps, Richie
[SCCMOG]

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where exactly you want to deploy your console application, you may be out of luck. According to [this page](http://communities.vmware.com/servlet/JiveServlet/previewBody/10141-102-3-13812/vSphere_VI3_Redistribution_Information.html) and [the most relevant forum post I could find](http://communities.vmware.com/message/1358342), the PowerCLI assemblies are *not* redistributable. Your best bet if you want to distribute this application outside your company is to use the Web Services SDK - a huge pain since you've already developed the app.

Assuming your application is for internal use only and you just want to deploy it on its destination server, you can do the following to reference the assemblies locally:

1. On the development machine, copy whichever PowerCLI .dlls you reference from the GAC (in %WINDIR%\assembly) to your solutions local directory.
2. Change your references in the project to point to the local versions of the .dlls.
3. Open the 'Properties' view for each of the references, and make sure 'Copy Local' is set to True.
4. Compile and deploy your console application (and it's coresident .dlls) to the target machine, it should reference them in the local directory and run without external dependencies.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I found out that the application is looking for a few registry keys that dont exist if you havent installed powercli

Answer (score 1):

You could also automate PowerCLI installation with a silent installation one-line Powershell script, if the problem is hiding the installation from the users.

> Invoke-Expression ("cmd /c '$powerCLIexeFilePath'/S /VADDLOCAL=ALL /V/qn")